# Stop my Meetup calendar syncing with my Google Calendar?

Tags: meetup

How do I stop my Meetup calendar syncing with my Google Calendar? It only asks which calendar you want to sync.

Answer (score 1):

In a web browser on a desktop:

Click on the little triangle next to "my calendars" > Settings

[image: where to find settings button to unsubscribe]

Scroll down until you see the Meetup calendar you want to stop syncing.

You can simply toggle the visibility of the calendar which will hide it from view and from syncing or click on the unsubscribe button and the Meetup calendar will be deleted from google calendar.

[image: closeup of toggle and unsubscribe button]